# In HMS - How is Cloud DB different from Huawei Cloud?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

Can you please tell me how is Cloud DB different from Huawei Cloud?

Can I have the same parent-child relationship while storing data as, i get on firebase in Huawei Cloud?

Also since Cloud DB is in beta, does that mean i cannot release the app on AppGallery Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud DB](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-introduction) is a scalable serverless database product provided by AppGallery Connect (AGC), it supports device-cloud data synergy management, provides a simple and easy-to-use native SDK for multiple platforms - Android apps, iOS apps, and web applications can directly access Cloud DB through the SDK. Cloud DB uses the data storage structure based on the object model. Data is stored in different Cloud DB zone as objects. Each object is a complete data record. An object type is used to define a set of stored objects. Different object types correspond to different data structures. A Cloud DB zone is an independent data storage area. Each Cloud DB zone has the same object type definition. You can define object types, create Cloud DB zones, and manage data on the AppGallery Connect console. Cloud DB supports multiple [Data Types](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-data-type), including simple character strings, digits, and texts.

When you say "Huawei Cloud", it is a broad term, this term mainly refers to the enterprise [Huawei Cloud](https://www.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/) similar to Alibaba Cloud, AWS, Azure, etc. There are many database services in Huawei Cloud such as RDS, GaussDB, DDS, DRS, DAS, etc. These databases are designed for enterprise use cases like IoT, e-commerce, finance, web, mobile gaming, e-government.

AGC Cloud DB is an alternative to replace Firebase Realtime Database however it simply stores an object and does not provide parent-child relationships. If you are looking for object type, parent-child relationship storage in Huawei Cloud, you can consider [GaussDB for Mongo](https://www.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/product/gaussdbformongo.html), [GaussDB for Cassandra](https://www.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/product/gaussdbforcassandra.html). Please consider how you would like to access data in your product before choosing the best database.

Although AGC Cloud DB is in beta, you can use it in your app (free tier quota only) and release it in AppGallery. Please check out the [supported platforms](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-introduction#h1-1608552720556) here and [quota/charges](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-introduction#h1-1611710493353) here.

[image]

When you apply for the Cloud DB service for the first time, if your application requires more resources than the free quota, or if you have enabled the free Cloud DB service but the free resource quota cannot meet your application requirements, you can download and fill in an application form, and send it as an attachment to agconnect@huawei.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cloud database Service of HUAWEI Cloud is used for web development and web application setup.
2. AGC's Cloud DB is a cloud database service for mobile application development.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-introduction

The beta state only restricts developer's access. Developer who have applied for the use can use the application as will, and they can release their applications, released applications are not affected.